# How to find the connections or relation between items in an array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Consider the following image, it is an array of items:

[image]

The items in the array are sorted by an attribute called `id` (the number in the black circle)

The attribute `id` is unique.

Each item has two additional attributes (in parenthesis within the circle) : `from` and `to`

Each item is *connected* or *related* to another by the `from` and `to` attributes. Example (not based in the above image):

```
Using kind of python syntax:

{id:1, from:a, to:b} --> {id:2, from:b,to:c} --> {id:3, from:c, to:a}
```

Think of the above example as a circular linked list as well.

There can be items that are not related to any others (for example the item with `id = 3-`).

The input is the `id` of an arbitrary item within the array.

The algorithm should retrieve any of the following results:

- An array of arrays.
- An array of circular linked lists.

Based on the image above, examples of the expected output are:

1.- Given the `id = 7`, the expected result is:

```
An array containing this single array (or its equivalent circular linked list).
That is, the items connected by the blue line.
If the items in the inner array are rotated by N, it's ok.

output = [
    [
        {id:7,  from:m, to:k},
        {id:8,  from:k, to:i},
        {id:10, from:i, to:b},
        {id:2,  from:b, to:e},
        {id:4,  from:e, to:h},
        {id:1,  from:h, to:l},
        {id:6,  from:l, to:m}
    ]
]
```

2.- Given the `id = 2`, the expected result is:

```
An array containing two arrays (or their equivalent circular linked list).
That is, the two collections of items connected by the red and the blue line.
If the items in the inner arrays are rotated by N, it's ok.

output = [
    [
        {id:2,  from:b, to:e},
        {id:5,  from:e, to:g},          
        {id:9,  from:g, to:i},
        {id:10, from:i, to:b}
    ],
    [           
        {id:2,  from:b, to:e},
        {id:4,  from:e, to:h},
        {id:1,  from:h, to:l},
        {id:6,  from:l, to:m},
        {id:7,  from:m, to:k},
        {id:8,  from:k, to:i},
        {id:10, from:i, to:b}
    ]
]
```

So, the questions is:

What could be the possible algorithm and data structure to resolve this problem?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like either homework or a coding challenge. Can you explain the motivation behind trying to solve this solution? It may help to determine your algorithm and data structure.

Comment: Hey @karnesJ.R, no, this is not homework, and yes...this sounds like a coding challenge but neither is. I have an app, where people post about places where they live and where they want get to. So, this algorithm could help them to find those places.

Comment: Well, the first thing you need to do is understand your data structure. What you have is a directed graph. There is a fantastic cycle detection tool in SAGE's graph library and SAGE works on Digraphs. You may want to start by looking there. If it's a practical application doing real things there's no reason to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @YvesDaoust 10 -> can be followed by both if the input id = 10, the output will be an array with 2 arrays, just like the example when input id = 2.

Comment: If you ensure the input must behave either in circular linked list or single left alone node, then isn't DFS  to find the cycles in graph can solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm trying to achieve is to find all cycles through a given vertex in a directed graph.

Modifying Johnson's algorithm is the correct solution to the problem. More information [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/60395/find-all-cycles-through-a-given-vertex).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample in Javascript, the description of the algorithm is in the comments, you can test it in the console in Chrome:

It's randomized, so you can run several tests.
If no path is found, an error is throw.

```js
/* First part to populate example data */
// The universo of people
var people = [];
// The single person item
var person = {};
var count;
// The lenth of the array
var len = 250;

// We're gonna create an array with the format
// [
//  {
//   "id": 1,
//   "origin": "a",
//   "destination": "b"
//  },
//  ...
// ]
for ( count = 1; count <= len; count ++) {
 
 var rnd = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 25);
 rnd = String.fromCharCode(97 + rnd)
 
 person = {};
 person.id = count;
 person.origin = rnd;
 
 rnd = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 25);
 rnd = String.fromCharCode(97 + rnd)
 person.destination = rnd;
 
 people.push( person ); 
}

// Here people is the universe of data
console.log ( people );

// Here we get a random person in people
// this person for run the test
rnd = Math.ceil(Math.random() * len);
person = people[rnd];
console.log( person );

// Next is the actual algorith
// The path is the array to return, obviously starting with person
path = [person];
// Route will the actual route of change to move the people and get where they want
// we call findMyPath a recursive function
route = findMyPath( person, person, path, people );
console.log('Done');
console.log( route );

/**
 * This recursive function actually implements the algorithm
 */
function findMyPath(source, currentItem, path, universe) {
 
 // The algorithm is:
 // Reverse query: 
 // Instead of find the people that is where I want to go,
 // find the people that want to go where I am
 // if at least one is where I want to go, then I'm done
 // if not, then repeat recursively for every finding
 
 // Holds the people that wanto to go where I am
 var findings = [];

 // Loop the universe
 for ( i = 0; i< universe.length; i++ ) {
  // tmp is the current item in the universe
  var tmp = universe[i]; 
  // If he/she want to go where I am
  if ( currentItem.origin == tmp.destination ) {
   // It's a finding!
   findings.push( tmp );
   // If he/she is where I want to go   
   if ( source.destination == tmp.origin ) {
    // It's a change complete, I'm done now
    console.log( 'Found the route of changes!' );    
    path.push( tmp );
    return path;
   }   
  }
 }
 
 // If we get here, we don't find a trade course yet,
 // the repeat recursively for all findinds
 for ( i = 0; i < findings.length; i++ ) {
  path.push( findings[0] );
  return findMyPath(source, findings[0], path, universe);
 } // end for
} // end function findMyPath
```

The results:

*IMPORTANT* The sample takes random numbers, this is just one run,
for every run, find different results, but the algorithm is the same

250 items in the array

```
[{"id":1,"origin":"h","destination":"p"},{"id":2,"origin":"s","destination":"e"},...
```

Complete json in http://desarrollo.espino.info/sampledata/20160707/results.json

The person for whom find the path: id 221 from "q" to "c"
The complete route of trading places

```
[
    {"id":221,"origin":"q","destination":"c"},
    {"id":26,"origin":"o","destination":"q"},
    {"id":28,"origin":"j","destination":"o"},
    {"id":31,"origin":"c","destination":"j"}
]
```

Comment: Looks pretty good. However, there are certain cases where a maximum call stack error raises. Check it out here: https://jsbin.com/sibitijego/edit?js,console

Comment: Those cases are "No solution", there is no path to return. So yo must increase the universe, in the real world, you'll need more customers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is just a structural way of a recursive algorithm to solve the problem:

- start with the given item (e.g. 7)
- search all other items for a connection (e.g. 7,8)
- build a chain this way. store all taken elements to prevent an item is taken twice. (e.g. 7,8,10,2)
- at some point there will be no more element found (e.g. 7,8,10,2,5,9)
- then delete the last item from the chain and search if the previous item has an other connection. (e.g. 7,8,10,2)
- decrease and increase the chain until you reach the starting item (e.g. 7,8,10,2,4,1,6,7)